# effectively sort big mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Say, I have a table with 1-2 millions of records. I have API to sort result array and retrieve first 25 rows. Basically, it´s a scoreboard table, so there may be many requests at a time.
My question is what should I do to optimize client-server data flow?
For example, how to:
  1. sort table itself, not result array, to just retrieve top 25 results?
  2. speed up requests?
My sample code is below.

```
mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);

mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
$sql = mysql_query("select pin,country,nickname,score from scoreboard order by score desc limit 0, 25");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[] = $row;
 $resulting_array['players'] = $output;
 print(json_encode($resulting_array));
 mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. build an index on column `score`
2. cache the result into a storage (like memcache, disk-cache, etc ...) for subsequent access
3. write a hook to purge / expire cache when the score has been updated

Comment: Thanks for reply. Would you be so kind to post link with more or less exhaustive tutorial? Or maybe sample php code.

Comment: http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/25/10-baby-steps-to-install-memcached-server-and-access-it-with-php/

Comment: thank you again! However, I have another question - imagine I want to move my database to the cloud, e.g. EC2. What should I do in this case?

Comment: does not matter ... if the memcache server is in the same network with your web server, so the network latency is minimum